# SELECT query with cross rows WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll try to explain the type of the query that I want:

Assume I have a table like this:

```
| ID | someID | Number |
|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1      | 10     |
| 2  | 1      | 11     |
| 3  | 1      | 14     |   
| 4  | 2      | 10     |  
| 5  | 2      | 13     |
```

Now, I want to find the someID that have a specific numbers (For example query for numbers 10, 11, 14 will return someID 1 and query for numbers 10, 13 will return 2). But, if someID contains all the query numbers but also more numbers, it will not return by the query. (For example query for 10, 11 will return nothing).
Is it possible?

Comment: Are duplicate numbers possible?

Comment: No, it's other table IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.someId
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.number IN (10,14,11)
GROUP BY t1.someID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.ID) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t1.someID=t2.someID)
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0269c/5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @podiluska answer working as well, but this way is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

```
select someID
from yourtable
where number in (10,11,14)
and not exists (select * from yourtable t2 where number not in(10,11,14) 
                 and t2.someid=yourtable.someid)
group by someID
having count(distinct ID) = 3
```

Where `3` is the number of items you are querying for

Comment: According to OP [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0269c/6) should return empty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you get the query numbers into a table variable (say it's called `@QNums`, with one column named `QNum`)) try

```
 Select distinct someId
 From table t
 Where exists (Select * from @QNums
               where QNum = t.Number)
   And not Exists (Select * From table t2
                   Where someId = t.someId
                      And not exists(Select * From @QNums
                                     where QNum = t3.Number))
```